# Maven Error- git-commit-id-plugin

Tags: git, maven

```
INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 24 17:37:45 UTC 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/29M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id      plugin:2.1.15:revision (default) on project common: The plugin          pl.project13.maven:git-commit-id-plugin:2.1.15 requires Maven version [3.1.1,) -> [Help 1]
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I received this error because i'm using IntelliJ which used an older bundled version of "Maven" by default.  It resets the default when you create a new project.

Make sure you set the following to your local maven folder, 
mine was C:\apache-maven-3.3.9

File -> Settings -> (Search "Maven") -> Maven Home Directory

Comment: In my case I discovered that NetBeans came with an older bundled version of Maven. Thanks for the hint :)

Answer (score 1):

Your maven version is outdated. Update to `3.1.1` or newer.

For the `git-commit-id-plugin` itself, have a look at this [example pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/jmini/8ae1c8d6a9aae63e6f6e81b31162d179).